# how to add serial number with text points in crystal report?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I want to design a crystal report that will have text with serial number(just like bullted points)

I also need to give spacing between numbers and text but I am not aware how to mange it. My text is not coming form Database, it can be text object or parameter. Please advice me how it can be done ?

Please see sample image here http://www.picupine.com/7871d07x

[image]

Comment: What links the serial number to the block of text, also how do you know the level (indentation) of the text block?

Answer (score 1):

Create groups with running totals

> [] = text field
>   {} = database, formula, running total fields

```
>Group Header {#Head_Count} {Head_Desc} 
>Group Header [{#Head_Count}.{#Head_Count2}]  {Head_2_Desc} 
>Detail
>Group Footer Suppressed
>Group Footer Suppressed
```

I'm not sure if the alpha bullets are able to be created in CR, but hopefully this puts you on the right track